# MySql select relative similar dates

Tags: mysql, date, time

I trying to select records from a table that are in the same time window, for example

```
record_date            |   record_data
4/20/2015 5:00:00 PM   |  23
4/20/2015 5:08:00 PM   |   3
4/20/2015 5:09:00 PM   |  98
```

if i set 2 minutes window will be result in:

```
4/20/2015 5:08:00 PM   |   3
4/20/2015 5:09:00 PM   |  98
```

but, if i choose 15 minutes window must get:

```
4/20/2015 5:00:00 PM   |  23
4/20/2015 5:08:00 PM   |   3
4/20/2015 5:09:00 PM   |  98
```

how can be done that ? BETWEEN or DATEDIFF statements needs a absolute date to compare with, and in this case the comparison must be relative to other records values and not to an external time.

Comment: you mean you want to get series of sequential records that are at most X minutes apart? if there is a subsequent sequence of events that also fall into that window, do you also want that included? eg if there were records from 6:00:00, 6:08:00 as well?

Comment: i want to group results happens in certain time window, for example 

[code]
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(record_data ORDER by record_date DESC SEPARATOR '#') as values FROM records WHERE  <<record_date BETWEEN 2 MINUTES FROM OTHER>>
[/code]

in 2 minute window adding 6:00:00 and 6:08:00 registers too, will get 4 rows in result:
 [code]
record_date | values
5:00:00        | 23
5:08:00        | 3#98    (5:08:00 and 5:09:00 are in the same time window)
6:00:00        | 10
6:08:00        | 4
[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql isn't very good at this (which means - there's nothing built in for it).

What we need to do, is associate a rank with each row, based on `record_date` order. ie, first row gets a rank of 1, the immediate next row by date gets a rank of 2, and so forth.

If we do that, we can then compare one row to the next fairly easily (ie compare `rank` to `rank + 1`)

This will give us pairings of rows, and the immediate next row by date, which we can then filter for those that are separated by your window of choice.

In order to transform that result, into a two column result, we need to repeat the query, `union` the results together, taking the first date and data in the first query, and the second date and data in the second query.

`union` is by default `distinct`, so we dont get any repeated rows.  This gives us the following query:

```
select * from (
  select t1.record_date, t1.record_data from
  (select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank, records.*
    from records, (select @rank := 0) q order by record_date asc) t1
  left join
  (select @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as rank, records.*
    from records, (select @rank2 := 0) q order by record_date asc) t2
  on t1.rank + 1 = t2.rank
  where t2.record_date < t1.record_date + interval 2 minute
union
select t2.record_date, t2.record_data from
  (select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank, records.*
    from records, (select @rank := 0) q order by record_date asc) t1
  left join
  (select @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 as rank, records.*
    from records, (select @rank2 := 0) q order by record_date asc) t2
  on t1.rank + 1 = t2.rank
  where t2.record_date < t1.record_date + interval 2 minute
) q
order by record_date asc;
```

with a [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4c74/13)

Or alternatively, you can do it in a slightly less over-the-top manner like this:

```
select *
  from (
    select r1.record_date, r1.record_data
      from records r1
        inner join records r2
          on r2.record_date = (select min(record_date) from records where record_date > r1.record_date)
      where r2.record_date < r1.record_date + interval 2 minute
    union
    select r2.record_date, r2.record_data
      from records r1
        inner join records r2
          on r2.record_date = (select min(record_date) from records where record_date > r1.record_date)
      where r2.record_date < r1.record_date + interval 2 minute
  ) q
  order by record_date asc;
```

Where we dont both with ranking, and just join directly to the next sequential date via a subquery that finds it.

[Updated demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4c74/22)

Comment: i'm checked the code in the demos and tried to understand JOIN and rank. but I think are a misunderstanding about the subjet, surely because i'm learning english yet, and can't be more accurate. I want to concat rows in the same time window, and in the example are rows have matched.  and can be more than too. 

April, 20 2015 17:00:00  23
April, 20 2015 17:08:00  3#98
April, 20 2015 18:00:00   23
April, 20 2015 18:08:00  3#98

18:08:00 includes 3#98, values of 18:08 and 18:09 por example.

Comment: @ramapunk did you look at the demos? both of the queries give you the result in the exact format you have requested, with the correct data. If there is something wrong with it, could you please provide additional sample data in the question, and expand on the required result?

Comment: yes sorry i undestand now!! but how can be splited distints times window when it occurs?
can be ranked like  record_date record_data and window_count for example?

Comment: @ramapunk you'd need to put that into another question, as it's sufficiently different from the original question

Comment: thanks! I opened a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093011/mysql-order-records-by-similar-time-and-same-user i hope you can help me!